# StorageFile throws error on renaming when got from OnFileActivated?

Tags: uwp

My UWP app throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied` error, when I try to rename a `StorageFile` got from `OnFileActivated` as shown below.

```
protected async override void OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    //----------------< OnFileActivated() >---------------- 
    //* when opened by file-extension 
    base.OnFileActivated(args);

    StorageFile file = (StorageFile) args.Files[0];
    await file.RenameAsync("hello.jpg"); //It throws error
    await file.DeleteAsync(); //It works
    return;
}
```

It seems strange, since, `DeleteAsync` works without exception. If the file is read-only, how I am able to delete that file? If the file is not read-only, why I am unable to rename that?

Scenario:
The `OnFileActivated` method is used to retrive the file when user click on a file with an extension registred by the app to handle. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation

I implemented `OnFileActivated` override method in app.cs file. I set File Type Associations in manifest. Everything works fine. I am able to handle the file and write content to it without any issues. Except the aforementioned issue.

Comment: Very unusual, an official answer here would be helpful. I guess it could be that you don't have access to the folder itself, but then it still does not explain the delete

Comment: Yep, I also think this is unusual, Could you share more `OnFileActivated` method? I could not get how do you get the file.

Comment: I have included more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the cause might be that you have only permission to the file itself, so deleting it is OK, but you don't have permission to the file location, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.FileActivatedEventArgs#remarks) for example says:

> You should not attempt to access the path of the file since your app may not have permission to the file’s location.

If you know the classic `System.IO` APIs, you may remember there is no `Rename` method. To rename, you actually need to call the [`Move` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move), which however clearly requires having permission to the folder itself. Hence, I suppose the `RenameAsync` uses a similar approach and does not allow you to perform this operation for this reason.